# I can get id and date but not the image url from Tumblr API

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I can get the id and date but not the photo itself from tumblr json api :(

**http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/11/**

```
$.getJSON("http://fuckyeahgirlswithvinylrecords.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.id).appendTo("#content");
        $("<div>").html(item.date).appendTo("#content");
        $("<img>").attr("src", item.photo-url-100).appendTo("#content");
    });
});
```

Comment: Change the way you are accessing to the field from `item.photo-url-100` to `item['photo-url-100']`

Comment: Just to clarify, this method will fail at some point. The Tumblr API v1 is depreciated and will stop working. You should be using v2 of the API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties can't have dashes in them. Use bracket notation:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFZ6R/

```
$("<img>").attr("src", item['photo-url-100']).appendTo("#content");
```

Answer (score 1):

change `item.photo-url-100` to `item['photo-url-100']`

Answer (score 1):

Call it as follows,

```
$.getJSON("http://fuckyeahgirlswithvinylrecords.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.id).appendTo("#content");
        $("<div>").html(item.date).appendTo("#content");
        $("<img>").attr("src", item['photo-url-100']).appendTo("#content");
    });
});
```